# Where to put new ruby library

Tags: ruby, web-services

I am currently writing a small ruby script.
I have following line in that script.

```
require 'amazon/search'
```

While running this script I am getting following error.

> C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- amazon/search (LoadError)
>           from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in`
>   require'

I have downloaded the (ruby-amazon-0.9.2.tar.gz) from http://www.caliban.org/ruby/ruby-amazon.shtml .
After extraction I am getting file system containing files and folders which contains lib/amazon/search also.
I have tried putting these files inside C:\Ruby200\lib. But it did not help.
Please help if you have any idea about this.

Comment: Okay! just see what is in your `PATH`?

Comment: another point do you have lower version Ruby?then try there,it will work there. because the same problem I also got with some gems with ruby2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `amazon/search.rb` file located? Is it in the same directory as your script? You probably just need to adjust your [load path](http://www.mikeheijmans.com/2010/09/using-load_path-for-better-library-loading-in-ruby/) to add whatever directory contains the `amazon/` directory. If the library is in `./lib`, you could do this with `$LOAD_PATH << './lib'`.

Of course, this kind of thing is usually better handled by a package management system like Rubygems, so if you can find a similar library that is packaged as a gem things will be easier.

Comment: Where is the `amazon/search.rb` file located, and where are you running your script from?